# Waiting for async calls of several components before rendering

Tags: reactjs

Having a parent with X child components in react. Each component (including the parent) performing async calls of unknown duration. Is there a way to coordinate the render once all async calls are done?

Simple example of my problem:

[image: Edit 9oz700rvmp]

Ideal solution: all numbers appear at the same time.

I am aware that i could move all async calls from the children up to the parent. What i don't like about it is that i only need the data in the specific child...

I thought of returning the promises from the children to the parent and using `Promise.all()` to set a boolean once all promises are resolved. But i couldn't make it work. Is this approach in general a "good idea"? Are there other ways of solving it without moving the async calls?

**Update:**

As requested by @zero298 the code example (check the CodeSandbox for a more detailed example):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

async function fetchData(setState) {
  const wait = getRandomInt(5);
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, wait * 1000));
  setState(wait);
}

function Tile() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setTitle);
  }, []);

  return <div>{title}</div>;
}

function App() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData(setTitle);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <Tile />
      <Tile />
      <Tile />
      <Tile />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Please put your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to follow React best practices and [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). So yes, you should move all async calls up to parent. Or go even further and user [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to centrally manage state of your app.

Technically you may leave async calls inside child components and somehow orchestrate them. But when your program became bigger, managing it becomes nigthmare, as data queries will be spread across almost all you files.

As always, after some time data fetched in one component only will be required in some other component and with your approach data reuse will be impossible